# Qual a diferença entre page e component?

Tags: ionic3, ionic2

Existe uma diferença entre o `generate page` e o `generate component`? quando devo usar um e não o outro? Isso muda algo em relação ao Lazyload?

Comment: comecei hoje a estudar esse treco ai, também não sei a diferença parece ser a mesma coisa, ou no máximo um *page* pode ser dividido em vários *component*